# how do i make disappearing buttons

Tags: java, button, overlay-icon-disappear

So i want to know how to make buttons disappear.  I have something like this...

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            (what goes here to make it disappear?)
        }
    });
```

I also want it to make other buttons disappear how do i do that?
I tried to do something like this...

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
linearlayoutbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use next code:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button1.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Or, use lambda expression in Java 8, for example:

```
button1.addActionListener(e -> button1.setVisible(false));
```

Comment: So how do i make other buttons disappear?  sorry but I'm new to this gui stuff

Comment: `[your gui object name].setVisible(flag)`, where flag is a boolean value: `true` or `false`. Are you understand me?

Comment: so i know that it needs to be higher in the code but i don't know how to make it do both i have something like this...

Comment: JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
     button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             button1.setVisible(false);
             button2.setVisible(false);
         }
     });
  button1.setBounds(48, 36, 39, 23);
  
  JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
  button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    button2.setVisible(false);
    button1.setVisible(false);
   }
  });
  button2.setBounds(97, 36, 38, 23);

Comment: JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
     button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             button1.setVisible(false);
             button2.setVisible(false);
         }
     });
  button1.setBounds(48, 36, 39, 23);
  
  JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
  button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    button2.setVisible(false);
    button1.setVisible(false);
   }
  });
  button2.setBounds(97, 36, 38, 23);

Comment: @HaydenIngram, What don't you understand here?